# iPhone 3GS Firmware for 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone, firmware, downgrade

I'm  a paid developer and I just realized that I need to downgrade a 3GS from 4.0 WITHOUT using XCode. Where can I get the firmware from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

Comment: Note that you cannot downgrade an iPhone 3GS or newer -- it just does not work. Apple has to verify every install and they will only allow a restore for the very latest firmware.