# Where can I download iPhone 3.1?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I develop for iPhone, and I want one of my test devices to have 3.1 on it.  It is nowhere to be found, at least not on the apple site. Current version is 4.x and that's the only one I can get there, besides I have 10.5 on my MAC so I have no real choice

Does anyone know where I can get this version

Comment: To the migrate voter: How would the people on SU be in a better position to answer this than the people on SO?

Comment: You might want try the [Apple Stack Exchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). Voting to close as 'off-topic' for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Boltclock, SU seemed a better fit than SO, the question doesn't seem to relate to programming, but more towards s specific hardware/software, which is closer to SU's remit than SO. Because SU is also likely not a perfect fit, I suggested the Apple SE site, where it should fit well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 3GS Firmware for 3.1.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032135/iphone-3gs-firmware-for-3-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

[version 3.1 for iPhone 3G/3GS/Touch](http://www.technobuzz.net/iphone-os-3-1-download-now-free/)

Comment: (But note that a 3GS and higher cannot use these, as Apple will refuse to allow the firmware restore on those devices.)

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** to downgrade (or even restore to *any* non-latest firmware) on an iPhone/iPod newer than an iPod touch 2G/iPhone 3G. This is because on the 3GS and newer devices, Apple implemented a system where they must agree to and sign every firmware restore.

You can read more about it here: http://saurik.com/id/12

To get around it, you can save your "SHSH", which is the signature Apple gives you when they approve a restore. To do this, check out [TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/), but be warned that you can only save it for the latest firmware (iOS 4.2 at the time of writing, since that is all Apple will sign), and cannot use this to go backwards unless you already saved it for your target firmware.

Comment: I don't have to downgrade becaused my current version on that device is 3.0.  I want to upgrade it to 3.1

Comment: @jkally: That's also not possible: you can't restore to 3.1 since Apple refuses to sign 3.1 at this point. You can /only/ restore to 4.2 -- or later, once newer firmwares come out. There's no way to use anything but the very latest.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all versions from [there](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firmware) :]

Comment: Except, you can't actually restore them on anything newer than a 3GS, due to Apple's "SHSH" signing system.

Comment: Can I upgrade with it a 3.0 3GS system to 3.1?